# how to put color to div on bottom using bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

As shown in image , there is navy blue color given to div inclinedly, how can do it using bootstrap in asp.net core project?

Comment: Are you able to use CSS on your own?

Comment: yes , how can put such color on bottom inclinedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do with bootstrap. However i have used `CSS Path` to create the same shape

You can use this [website](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to make CSS Path

```css
.backgroundCover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#clipPath {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundCover">
  <div id="clipPath">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @teju Please upvote and accept my answer, if its solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements to create rectangles and then rotate them. This has higher support rate by using `transform` instead of `clip-path` in terms of old browsers.

```css
body { background: black; }

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  
  background: white;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  
  position: relative;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: '';
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  background: #0d2e41;
  
  bottom: -25%;
}

.container:before {
  transform: rotateZ(135deg);
  
  left: -25%;
}

.container:after {
  transform: rotateZ(225deg);
  
  right: -25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```